# Lock message to single subscriber using Topics?

Tags: servicebus, azureservicebus

I apologize for such a non-specific question, but I'm in the research stage of a project and had one question about the Windows Enterprise Service Bus that I can't seem to get a clear answer to.

The project entails users sending different types of "jobs" as messages to the ESB, which should then hand off the message to one of several available severs for background processing.

Considering we will have multiple different "jobs", I thought it would be best to create a subscription per background server and have each message be filtered by it's type, this way we wouldn't have to build in a dequeuer ourselves. However, my concern is that I will not be able to lock a message to one subscription in time and the message will be processed by each subscription that handles the particular type of "job".

I've been hard-pressed to find good research material on this subject and it seems that a Queue and a Subscription are mostly handled the same with the Service Bus, but the only part I can't find is when you lock a message on a topic, can it be locked only to one subscriber.

Thanks for any help or guidance towards the answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A message sent to a topic is essentially duplicated/copied to all subscribers. So there is no way for one subscriber to "lock" the message. The approach for this is to have a single subscriber by type, then have multiple receivers associated with that subscriber.

Unlike subscribers, receivers are competitive, giving you the "only one get its" behavior you appear to be after.

Comment: Thanks for the reply! Thinking in terms of a Subscriber having Receivers makes this much easier than what I had envisioned.